# Why ReactJS Error Boundary ignores children property

Tags: reactjs

Please see below code.

The Error boundary component is straight from ReactJS online example.
I am trying to use the same for MyComponent - which is functional component.

Queestion is why the error boundary is not showing "Something is wrong" message?
Any other alternative to this? or any reference on how to refactor the existing component? It seems, the code never reaches componentDidCatch.

```
  class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { error: null, errorInfo: null };
  }

  componentDidCatch(error, errorInfo) {
    // Catch errors in any components below and re-render with error message
    this.setState({
      error: error,
      errorInfo: errorInfo
    })
    // You can also log error messages to an error reporting service here
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.errorInfo) {
      // Error path
      return (
        <div>
          <h2>Something went wrong.</h2>
          <details style={{ whiteSpace: 'pre-wrap' }}>
            {this.state.error && this.state.error.toString()}
            <br />
            {this.state.errorInfo.componentStack}
          </details>
        </div>
      );
    }
    // Normally, just render children
    return this.props.children;
  }  
}

const MyComp = ( { children } ) => {

  return (

     <div className='tile-h'>
       {children.l} // <-- this should fail and the component.
     </div>

  )

}
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <ErrorBoundary>
        <p>lorem ipsum</p>
        <MyComp><h2>test</h2></MyComp>
      </ErrorBoundary>
      <hr />

    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Or in other way, what it the best way to create Error Boundary for the component which is similar to the "MyComponent"?

Comment: `children.l` will return `undefined` if it doesn't exist. It won't throw an error.

Comment: @wdm makes sense to me, then how do I test this - i.e. how do we check whether error boundary is working or not?

Comment: Try `children.l.foo`